# H dome transformation built into MATLAB? For instance, in one of the MATLAB toolboxes?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Is there an h dome transformation built into MATLAB in one of the toolboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a free implementation of the h dome transform on [this site](http://www.cs.tut.fi/sgn/csb/subcell/) as supplementary information to an [article](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/11/248) that compares it to other detection schemes.

Answer (score 0):

See the functions [imhmin](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/imhmin.html) and [imhmax](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/imhmax.html) in the Image Processing Toolbox.